# No direct packet access in BPF program with just CAP_BPF?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, linux-capabilities

Up until Linux 5.8 `CAP_SYSADMIN` was required to load any but the most basic BPF program. The recently introduced `CAP_BPF` is a welcome addition as it allows to run software leveraging BPF with less privileges.

Certain types of BPF programs can access packet data. The pre-4.7 way of doing it is via `bpf_skb_load_bytes()` helper. As the verifier got smarter, it became possible to perform "direct packet access", i.e. to access packet bytes by following pointers in the context structure. E.g:

```c
static const struct bpf_insn prog[] = {
    // BPF_PROG_TYPE_SK_REUSEPORT: gets a pointer to sk_reuseport_md (r1).

    // Get packet data pointer (r2) and ensure length >= 2, goto Drop otherwise
    BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_DW, BPF_REG_2, BPF_REG_1,
                offsetof(struct sk_reuseport_md, data)),
    BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_DW, BPF_REG_3, BPF_REG_1,
                offsetof(struct sk_reuseport_md, data_end)),
    BPF_MOV64_REG(BPF_REG_4, BPF_REG_2),
    BPF_ALU64_IMM(BPF_ADD, BPF_REG_4, 2),
    BPF_JMP_REG(BPF_JGT, BPF_REG_4, BPF_REG_3, /* Drop: */ +4),

    // Ensure first 2 bytes are 0, goto Drop otherwise
    BPF_LDX_MEM(BPF_H, BPF_REG_4, BPF_REG_2, 0),
    BPF_JMP_IMM(BPF_JNE, BPF_REG_4, 0, /* Drop: */ +2),

    // return SK_PASS
    BPF_MOV32_IMM(BPF_REG_0, SK_PASS),
    BPF_EXIT_INSN(),

    // Drop: return SK_DROP
    BPF_MOV32_IMM(BPF_REG_0, SK_DROP),
    BPF_EXIT_INSN()
};
```

It is required to ensure that the accessed bytes are within bounds explicitly. The verifier will reject the program otherwise.

The program above loads successfully if the caller bears `CAP_SYSADMIN`. Supposedly, `CAP_BPF` should suffice as well, but it doesn't (Linux 5.13). Earlier kernels behave similarly. The verifier output follows:

```
Permission denied
0: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)
1: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +8)
2: (bf) r4 = r2
3: (07) r4 += 2
4: (2d) if r4 > r3 goto pc+4
R3 pointer comparison prohibited
processed 5 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

I understand that arbitrary pointer comparison is restricted as it reveals kernel memory layout. However, comparing a pointer to a packet data offset by a certain amount with a pointer to the packet end is safe.

I'd like to find a way to load the program without granting `CAP_SYSADMIN`.

1. Is there a way to write bounds checks in a way that doesn't trigger pointer comparison error?

   The relevant code is in [`check_cond_jmp_op()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17-rc6/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L9315). It looks like one can't get away with pointer comparison, even with the latest kernel version.
2. If there's no way to write bounds check in a way that keeps verifier happy, I wonder if lifting the limitation is on the roadmap.
3. As a workaround, I can grant `CAP_PERFORM` on top of `CAP_BPF`, removing the "embargo" on pointer comparison. The program loads successfully. I can probably restrict `perf_event_open()` and other superfluous bits with seccomp. Doesn't feel nice though.

[Reproducer](https://gist.github.com/mejedi/3984cb30a22d04fcb013b0855f9e4e71).

Comment: The [`libcap` document snippet](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/doc/values/39.txt) for `CAP_BPF` indicates that `CAP_PERFMON` is needed for pointer to integer conversions. It looks like the developers were pretty explicit about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make direct packet accesses in your program, you will need `CAP_PERFMON` in addition to `CAP_BPF`. I'm not aware of any way around it.

**Why?**

Because of Spectre vulnerabilities, someone able to perform arithmetic on unbounded pointers (i.e., all [except stack and map value pointers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.13/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L6868)) can [read arbitrary memory via speculative out-of-bounds loads](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f232326f6966cf2a1d1db7bc917a4ce5f9f55f76).

Such operations thus need to be forbidden for unprivileged users. Allowing `CAP_BPF` users to perform those operations would essentially give read access to arbitrary memory to `CAP_BPF`. For those reasons, I doubt this limitation will be lifted in the future.